# Typescript generic type for an array input

Tags: typescript

I have a question around generic type for array input. I have a function called `useForm` and it accepts the following options

```
export interface DataType {
  [key: string]: FieldValue;
}

export type FieldValue = boolean | string | string[] | number | {};

export default function useForm<Data extends DataType>(
  { mode, validationSchema, defaultValues, validationFields }: Props<Data> = {
    mode: 'onSubmit',
    defaultValues: {},
  },
): UseFormFunctions<Data> {
}

export interface Props<Data> {
  mode: 'onSubmit' | 'onBlur' | 'onChange';
  defaultValues?: { [key: string]: any };
  validationFields?: string[]; // how do i use generic type here to only allow key from FormData
  validationSchema?: any;
}

type FormData = {
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
}

const { register } = useForm<FormData>({
  validationFields: ['test'] // should throw error because it's not firstname or lastname
})
```

i want it to throw an type error when FormData type is not found.

Comment: could you post the signature of `useForm`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir sure, thanks for taking a look

Comment: can you post the code for UseFormFunctions and DataType

Comment: sure @ShadabFaiz thanks heaps for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `keyof` to get a union of keys in `Data`:

```
export default function useForm<Data extends DataType>(
  { mode, validationSchema, defaultValues, validationFields }: Props<Data> = {
    mode: 'onSubmit',
    defaultValues: {},
  },
): UseFormFunctions<Data> {
  return null!;
}

export interface Props<Data> {
  mode: 'onSubmit' | 'onBlur' | 'onChange';
  defaultValues?: { [key: string]: any };
  validationFields?: Array<keyof Data>; // how do i use generic type here to only allow key from FormData
  validationSchema?: any;
}

type FormData = {
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
}

const { register } = useForm<FormData>({
  mode: 'onBlur',
  validationFields: ['test'] // error now
})
```

Comment: Nice! didn't know you can do that, any chance you can share the reference? would like to learn

Comment: @Bruce This is a good start: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types

Comment: quick question Array<keyof Data> how to convert into [] version

Comment: cause i had an eslint error: 18:22  error  Array type using 'Array<T>' is forbidden. Use 'T[]' instead  @typescript-eslint/arra , thanks bill

Comment: @Bruce `(keyof Data)[]` but i find this particularly ugly .. for complex types Array<T> is much better ..

Comment: thanks a lot, it is ugly... it's weird as well () instead of <>